# Https site version shows the Apache start page, but http works well

Tags: wordpress, centos

Hi I am having a little problem after using permalinks wordpress, the https version of the site shows the Apache start page. On the http version, the site and all permalinks work fine. I also want to say that without using permalinks, the site on http and https works well. I am using CentOS 8

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress"
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
        allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ssls/cazzy_store.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssls/cazzy.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/ssls/cazzy_store.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding AllowOverride All ”to the <Directory” in my httpd.conf file but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this to my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>
```